# arrow in a triangle

Tags: commutative-diagrams

I am trying to put a `\Rightarrow` inside a triangle.

I have the code for square but I am not able to use it to do the same for a triangle.

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed with up-to-date TeX systems
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % do you *really* need it?


\usepackage{hyperref}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\textheight 9.3in 
\textwidth 6.5in
\calclayout


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[dd,"a"'] \arrow[rr, "b"] &  & B \arrow[dd, "c"] \\
&  &  \\
C  \arrow[Rightarrow, shorten >=20pt, shorten <=20pt, uurr] \arrow[rr, "d"] &  & D
\end{tikzcd}.

\end{document}
```

I am looking for something like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very similar to the example on the bottom of p. 8 of the manual. The trick is to give the edge labels names, and use those names in some `\arrow[from=<from_name>,to=<to_name>,...]`, where `...` represents other options such as `Rightarrow` and/or edge labels.

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
your ``square''
\[\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[dd,"a"'] \arrow[rr, "b"] &  & B \arrow[dd, "c"] \\
&  &  \\
C  \arrow[Rightarrow, shorten >=20pt, shorten <=20pt, uurr] \arrow[rr, "d"] &  & D
\end{tikzcd}\]
\bigskip

``triangle''
\[\begin{tikzcd}
& |[alias=C]| C \arrow[dl,"a"'] \arrow[dr, "b"]  &  \\[2em]
A   
\arrow[rr, "" {name=U}] &  & B
\arrow[Rightarrow,from=U,to=C,shorten >=1ex,shorten <=1ex]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\bigskip

``triangle'' with label
\[\begin{tikzcd}
& |[alias=C]| C \arrow[dl,"a"'] \arrow[dr, "b"]  &  \\[2em]
A   
\arrow[rr, "u" {name=U}] &  & B
\arrow[Rightarrow,from=U,to=C,shorten >=1ex,shorten <=1ex,"h"]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\bigskip

``row''
\[\begin{tikzcd}
A   \arrow[rr,bend left, "" {name=U}] 
\arrow[rr,bend right, "" {name=V}] &  & B
\arrow[Rightarrow,from=U,to=V,shorten <=1ex]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\bigskip

``row'' with label
\[\begin{tikzcd}
A   \arrow[rr,bend left, "u" {name=U}] 
\arrow[rr,bend right, "v" {name=V}] &  & B
\arrow[Rightarrow,from=U,to=V,shorten <=1ex,"h"]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. It answered my question, Can you also say if there is any way to label the arrow $\Rightarrow$?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Sure, you can add it in quotes like in the other arrows, e.g. `\arrow[Rightarrow,"h",from=U,to=V,shorten <=1ex]`. If you add a prime, `\arrow[Rightarrow,"h"',from=U,to=V,shorten <=1ex]`, the labels side will be swapped.

Comment: Thanks. :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do these fairly simply using [xypic](http://xy-pic.sourceforge.net/), but I would not claim that the [manual](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/doc/xyguide.pdf) or the [reference guide](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/doc/xyrefer.pdf) are very easy to follow.  The detail you need is in section 25 of the reference guide.

This is what I managed to produce:

[image: Two two cells]

And this is the source code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\xyoption{2cell}
\UseAllTwocells
\begin{document}

\[
    \xymatrix@C=14pt{ 
              & C \ar[dl] & \\
    A \ar[rr] &           & B \ullowertwocell<0>{<-2>}
    }
\]

\[
    \xymatrix@C=48pt{A\rtwocell & B}
\]

\end{document}
```

### Notes

- The second (lower) picture is the simpler.  All you need here is the default `\rtwocell` to make the two arrows from `A` to `B` with the orientation arrow pointing down.
- In the upper picture I've used extra `&` markers to fit the three cells into a 3x2 grid, and then I have adjusted the column widths (with `@C=14pt`) to make it look more equilateral.
- The arrows from A to B and from C to A are regular simple `\ar` arrows.
- The arrow from B to C is "the lower half of a two cell arrow going up-left", this translates to `\ullowertwocell`, as shown
- But to get this arrow straight you have to add a "nudge" immediately after it with `<0>`
- And then to move the broad arrow in to the right place, you have to nudge that as well with `{<-2>}`

Comment: This is nice. Thank you :)